# Django signal to delete file on aws s3 not working

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, signals

I have written the pre_save signal in Django to auto-delete the user's old profile_pic if the user updates its profile_pic. This is my code.

```py
@receiver(pre_save, sender=User)
def delete_file_on_update(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    Delete the user's old profile pic file when user update the profile
    and return the status True or False i.e where old pic is deleted or
    not.
    """

    # If instance is saving for first time in database, don't delete
    # profile_pic file.
    try:
        old_file = sender.objects.get(pk=instance.pk).profile_pic
    except sender.DoesNotExist:
        return False

    # If user has not updated profile pic, don't delete profile_pic
    # file.
    new_file = instance.profile_pic
    if old_file == new_file:
        return False
    
    try:
        old_file.delete(save=False)
        return True
    except Exception:
        return False
```

This was working fine when storage was local but when I used the AWS s3 storage, It is not deleting the old profile_pic anymore. Also on debugging this signal is get called on each pre_save of user and old_file.delete(save=false) is also executing but the file is not deleting on AWS s3.

Comment: Where is your code to delete the object from S3?

Comment: in last try-except, I have written old_file.delete(save=false), old_file is user's old profile_pic and is a image-file object.

Comment: The only reason that come to my mind is S3 misconfiguration but the question needs clarification about that part. Can you save a profile pic with S3? Are your local environment has access to S3 bucket with the required permissions to create/delete objects? It is always better for contributors if you share more details (such as related settings file content) before submitting your question.

Comment: User's profile_pic is uploading on AWS s3. But how can I know if I have permission to delete an object on s3 from local environment.

Comment: Add logging, especially in your exception handlers.

Comment: what is logging?

Comment: See [Django logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/logging/). At the very least, add print statements into your code at key points so that you know what's going on. In particular, you should log any exceptions that you catch. You can't fix problems if you don't know what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

delete_file_on_update is used elsewhere?

If you have named another event with the same name, only the last one will be recognized.

If this is the problem, I recommend changing the name of each of these events